Не получается обновить getter, используя vuex
Мне нужно, чтобы обновился геттер isUserSignedIn. В моём понимании я делаю всё правильно - делаю await, чтобы посмотреть обновился ли массив. Логика: сначала пользователя регистрирует, потом отправляется письмо на почту с верификацией, пользователь подтверждает и возвращается обратно и заходит спокойно в профиль, в моём же случае страницу после подтверждения нужно обновить - хотелось бы от этого избавиться.
Вывод в консоли:
User data fetched: {email: 'myemail@gmail.com', phoneNumber: '*', isAdmin: false, isVerified: false, displayName: 'name name', …}
<script>
import useValidate from "@vuelidate/core";
import useValidationRules from "@/firebase/Validations/RegisterValidationRules.js";

import {
  updateUserProfile,
  checkIfFirstUser,
  registerWithEmailAndPassword,
  sendEmailVerify,
} from "@/firebase/Authentication/EmailAuth/index.js";
import { showErrorToast, showInfoToast } from "@/firebase/Toasts";
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "RegisterFormComponent",
  setup() {
    const { state, rules } = useValidationRules();
    const v$ = useValidate(rules, state);

    return {
      state,
      v$,
      ...mapGetters(["isUserSignedIn"]),
    };
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["setIsLoading"]),
    async registerUser() {
      // Check if form has validation errors
      this.v$.$validate();
      if (this.v$.$error) {
        showErrorToast("Form has validation errors!");
        return;
      }

      try {
        // Check if user is the first user
        const isFirstUser = await checkIfFirstUser();
        const displayName = `${this.state.firstName} ${this.state.lastName}`;

        // Prepare user data
        const userData = {
          email: this.state.email,
          phoneNumber: this.state.phoneNumber,
          isAdmin: isFirstUser,
        };

        this.setIsLoading(true);

        // Register user with email and password
        const userCredential = await registerWithEmailAndPassword(
          this.state.email,
          this.state.password.password
        );

        await updateUserProfile(userCredential.user, displayName, userData);

        await sendEmailVerify(userCredential.user);
        showInfoToast(
          `Please verify your email address to proceed. A verification email has been sent to ${this.state.email}.`
        );

        do {
          await this.$store.dispatch("fetchUserData");
          await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
        } while (!this.$store.getters.isUserSignedIn);

        this.navigateToProfilePage(true);
      } catch (error) {
        switch (error.code) {
          case "auth/email-already-in-use":
            showErrorToast(
              "Email is already in use. Please use a different email address."
            );
            break;
          case "auth/invalid-email":
            showErrorToast("Invalid email address.");
            break;
          case "auth/invalid-password":
            showErrorToast(
              "Invalid password. Password must be at least 6 characters long."
            );
            break;
          case "auth/operation-not-allowed":
            showErrorToast(
              "Email/password accounts are not enabled. Please contact support."
            );
            break;
          case "auth/too-many-requests":
            showErrorToast(
              "Too many registration attempts. Please try again later."
            );
            break;
          default:
            showErrorToast(
              "Error occurred during registration. Please try again later."
            );
            console.error(error.code);
        }
      } finally {
        this.setIsLoading(false);
      }
    },
    navigateToProfilePage(registered) {
      this.$router.push({
        name: "AppProfile",
        query: { registered },
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>

Само хранилище:
import { createStore } from "vuex";

import { getCurrentUser } from "@/firebase/firebase";
import { signOutUser } from "@/firebase/Authentication/SignOut";

export default createStore({
  state: {
    userData: null,
    isLoading: false,
    showVerifyEmailMessage: false,
  },
  mutations: {
    setUserData(state, userData) {
      state.userData = userData;
      if (userData && userData.isVerified) {
        console.log("User is verified");
      }
    },
    setIsLoading(state, isLoading) {
      state.isLoading = isLoading;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    async fetchUserData({ commit }) {
      try {
        const userData = await getCurrentUser();
        commit("setUserData", userData);
        console.log("User data fetched:", userData);
        return userData;
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching user data:", error);
        throw error;
      }
    },
    async signOut({ commit }) {
      try {
        await signOutUser();
        commit("setUserData", null);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error signing out:", error);
      }
    },
    setIsLoading({ commit }, isLoading) {
      commit("setIsLoading", isLoading);
    },
  },
  getters: {
    isUserSignedIn: (state) =>
      state.userData !== null && state.userData.isVerified,
    isAdmin: (state) => state.userData !== null && state.userData.isAdmin,
    userDataLoaded: (state) => state.userData !== null,
    isLoading: (state) => state.isLoading,
  },
});

Файл инициализации firebase:
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { onSnapshot, doc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.VUE_APP_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.VUE_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.VUE_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.VUE_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.VUE_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.VUE_APP_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.VUE_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app);
const db = getFirestore(app);
const storage = getStorage(app);

const getCurrentUser = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    onAuthStateChanged(
      auth,
      async (user) => {
        if (user) {
          try {
            const userRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);
            onSnapshot(userRef, (docSnapshot) => {
              if (docSnapshot.exists()) {
                const userData = {
                  ...docSnapshot.data(),
                  isVerified: user.emailVerified,
                  displayName: user.displayName,
                  id: user.uid,
                };
                console.log("User data fetched:", userData);
                resolve(userData);
              } else {
                reject(new Error("User data not found"));
              }
            });
          } catch (error) {
            reject(error);
          }
        } else {
          resolve(null);
        }
      },
      reject
    );
  });
};

export { auth, db, storage, getCurrentUser };



А если заменить на isUserSignedIn: (state) => () => state.userData?.isVerified ?? false, и while (!this.$store.getters.isUserSignedIn()); — то начинает без обновления страницы работать, или не?

@yar85, к сожалению, не помогло, выводит false в этой части кода:
do {
          console.log(this.$store.getters.isUserSignedIn());

          await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
        } while (!this.$store.getters.isUserSignedIn());


Тогда не знаю :( Геттеры-методы должны быть без кэширования, и фиг знает почему этот геттер в данном случае стейт не отражает. А там в серверном ответе свойство isVerified точно-преточно меняет значение на true со временем?

@yar85 только после обновления страницы кнопкой f5

@yar85, может быть это из-за того, что данные о пользователе не обновляются? Приложил файл инициализации firebase

Может. Если имеется тестовая почта, попробуй насильно обновить токен пользователя после подтверждения. И в том случае если это сработает, можно привязать это действие к кнопке типа "я подтвердил" которую юзер сможет нажать после верификации мыла (т.к. слишком часто рефрешить в цикле не получится).

А если я не правильно понял вопрос и он был в том "может ли не вызываться коллбэк onAuthStateChanged при валидации" - фиг его знает)) Если подозрение на это, то можно попробовать читать флаг слегка иначе: getAuth().currentUser?.emailVerified, на базе того как доки предлагают... там пример чтения данных юзера все-таки без обзервера с коллбэком (который судя по всему только для реакции на логин/логаут).
